# Changing tree node font color

Tags: java, css, gwt, gxt

Here is my problem:

I use a Tree to render a data structure and I also have a list of objects that gives extra information between two objects of the tree (that are not especially liked by the tree structure). What I want to do is to highlight the two element of the tree involved in the object select in my list. So I want to change the font color of the tree nodes involved with the object I select in the list when I select it.

I have tried several things. Two of the were to use a ValueProvider whose getValue method return value with css but it actually displays the css as text. In this example I changed Tree by Tree but the result is slightly the same. Here is the code of that solution:

```
submissionTree = new Tree<SubmissionMenuData, SafeHtml>(submissionTreeStore, new ValueProvider<SubmissionMenuData, SafeHtml>() {
            @Override
            public SafeHtml getValue(SubmissionMenuData object) {
                if (object.isActiveLink()){
                    return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString("<span style='color:blue;'>"+object.getValue()+"</span>");
                }else{
                    return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(object.getValue());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(SubmissionMenuData object, SafeHtml value) {
                // ... not relevant here
            }

            @Override
            public String getPath() {
                return "value";
            }
        });
```

My second idea was to use one of these two methods but neither of them worked (nothing happened actually):

```
view.getSubmissionTree().getView().getElement(elementToChangeColor).getStyle().setColor("blue");
view.getSubmissionTree().getView().getElement(elementToChangeColor).addClassName("blue-font");
```

However, even though it is not what I want to do these following method works.

```
view.getSubmissionTree().getView().getElement(elementToChangeColor).getStyle().setBackgroundColor("blue");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ValueProvider` isn't meant for styling - it passes the value to be shown (or processed). So if you pass an HTML element, by default it will be printed out as you described.

One possible solution is to set a custom cell. Change your Tree to `Tree<SubmissionMenuData, SubmissionMenuData>` and return the object:

```
submissionTree = new Tree<SubmissionMenuData, SubmissionMenuData>(submissionTreeStore, new ValueProvider<SubmissionMenuData, SubmissionMenuData>() {
    @Override
    public SubmissionMenuData getValue(SubmissionMenuData object) {
        return object; // just return the object itself - how to display it will be handled later
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(SubmissionMenuData object, SubmissionMenuData value) {
        // ... not relevant here
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return "value";
    }
});
```

Now create and add a cell:

```
submissionTree.setCell(new AbstractCell<SubmissionMenuData>() {
    @Override
    public void render(Context context, SubmissionMenuData object, SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder)
    {
        if (object.isActiveLink()){
            safeHtmlBuilder.appendHtmlConstant("<span style='color:blue;'>"+object.getValue()+"</span>");
        else
            safeHtmlBuilder.appendEscaped(object.getValue());
    }
});
```

If you can't or don't want to change the type of your tree, you can create an `AbstractCell<SafeHtml>` instead. But then you will need to find your current object by evaluating the context (column and index) and loading the object from your tree store.

Comment: Of course thank you. I did not think to change the tree type for that.